How can I dry out a wall soaked by a roof leak?
We had our roof repaired recently as the flashing had failed. I think water had been entering for a considerable time without us realising. A plasterer came and did a 'fix it' job and unfortunately didn't wait until the wall was completely dry. I think he stripped it back and filled it but not sure with what. After painting it, within a couple of weeks, staining started to appear and now it looks terrible, much worse than before. He said he'll come back and sort it but it just doesn't seem to be drying out, especially the area which he filled, see the photo.
The roof was repaired in January and the roofer assures us it's fixed and will just take time for the wall to dry. I'm just not sure what to do next, strip the wall back to the brick work and let it dry out? It's a rental property so I need to try and get it back to dry state as soon as possible. Any advice much appreciated please? I'm still waiting to hear from the plasterer!
I've had the heating on and a dehumidifier for the last 2 weeks to see if this helps. It's a Victorian terrace.


Damp/wetness needs air movement and time to dry.  Most building materials can soak water deep into their thickness.  Once a wet section is closed up before a full dry, it can take months to dry.  Might need to open holes(bottom and top) in the wall/s and have fans blowing air into the wall.

also: any staining will simply bleed through new latex paint and re-appear if it hasn't been pre-primed with something made for the purpose e.g. Killz or Zinsser. It will also bleed through off-the-shelf spackle. Not sure about plaster per se

Airflow and heat.
Airflow to remove moisture from the area (and ultimately the building). Heat to lower the relative humidity and promote evaporation.
Get fans on the damp areas from any accessible point, including the attic. Use infrared lamps, portable heaters and the home's HVAC system to keep the temperature up, even if it means cracking windows to ventilate excess heat.
Only after everything is thoroughly dry should you attempt to repair or repaint the wall. Doing it too soon will simply repeat what you have here.
